# F12 no longer works in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2005, keyboard-shortcuts

This is driving me crazy. Ever since I installed ReSharper 4, <kbd>F12</kbd> no longer seems to work. If you look at the all the ReSharper short cuts in the Goto sub menu Declaration doesn't have any assigned!

The only way I can go to declaration is by using <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>`</kbd> and then selecting Declaration.

I have tried un-installing and re-installing ReSharper with no luck, I have also, in ReSharper option asked it to use the default Visual Studio Key Bindings but that doesn't to work either.

Interestingly, when I do use <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>`</kbd> I actually get two entries for the Declaration option.

Has anyone come across this problem?

I am using Visual Studio 2005 SP1.

Comment: Sometimes we have to make sure that the source code is included in the project, esp. if none of the below solutions worked out.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I have had a few occasions where Resharper and Visual Studio keybindings got mixed up and I had problems sorting them out.

If it is only one or two bindings you care about then you can change them by going to the

Tools->Customize->Keyboard menu option.

Comment: Thanks! You saved me lots of right button clicks per day! :-)

Comment: This may not work sometimes. I have to downvote it. Please see the more complete answer by @Ryan below.

Comment: Just "Reset" the settings here.

Answer (score 279):

I ran into the same issue and resolved it by first resetting my Visual Studio keyboard mappings:

> Tools > Options > Keyboard > Reset

Then going into the ReSharper options and applying the scheme:

> Resharper > Options > Visual Studio Integration > Apply Scheme

*Update:*

For VS2017 onwards:

> Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard > Reset

For Resharper 2017.2:

> Resharper > Options > Environment > Keyboard & Menus > Keyboard Shortcuts > Apply Scheme

Comment: Still a solution when resharper 7 and vs 2012 get mixed up. Thanks for this advice.

Comment: In Resharper 8 it is (as mentioned in other answer):

Resharper > Options > Environment > Keyboard & Menus > (Select Visual Studio under Keyboard Shortcuts) > Apply Scheme > Save

Comment: @RahulR. I edited it accordingly, but I kept the answer as it will still be true if someone uses v8 or earlier. I'd recommend stackoverflowers to push up this answer as this does work.

Comment: and don't forget to restart VS, had to do in my case :)

Comment: This! I had the same issue. It was driving me nuts. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I had this problem and spent ages trying to fix it but no matter how many times I assigned F12 to go to definition it wouldn't work.  THANKS !! I reset the keyboard then changed Resharper from default to other then back to default and saved... this did the trick.. hope it helps someone else

Comment: for me, it is still not working :( after applying both settings(resharper and vs)

Comment: To be clear, the last step is:
Resharper > Options > Environment > Keyboard & Menus > Keyboard Shortcuts > Resharper keyboard scheme: Visual Studio > Apply Scheme

Comment: Doesn't work with visual studio professional 2017 veersion 15.6.2 and Resharper Ultimate 2017.2.2.

Answer (score 22):

For ReSharper 8 and Visual Studio 2012:

> Tools > Options > Keyboard > Reset

Then going into the ReSharper options and applying the scheme:

> Resharper > Options > Environment > Keyboard & Menus > (Select Visual Studio under Keyboard Shortcuts) > Apply Scheme > Save

Answer (score 21):

I had this problem and it was resolved by following the steps described in the picture:

Open Visual Studio Tabs on the path: Tools>>Options>>Keyboard

[image]

Open Visual Studio Tabs on the path: Resharper>>Options>>Keyboard & Menus and Do the following:

[image]

And Then Reopen the path above and do the following:

[image]

Finally, close the Visual Studio and open it.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me be patient with resharper after re-loading visual studio.

Answer (score 8):

I had this issue in VS2015 using Resharper 9.1.3, I tried Ryan's answer but it still didn't work.

- After doing the steps Ryan outlined, I clicked F12 where Resharper asks *What do you want to do?*, I select *Use Visual Studio commands*. Still doesn't work.
- Tools > Options > Keyboard > Select *ReSharper.ReSharper_GotoNextHighlight* from command list box
- Change *Shortcuts for selected command* to *F12 (Text Editor)*, click *Remove* and *OK*.

After this it works!

Comment: I'd say THIS is the fix. After selecting to use the VS command instead of Resharper the first time you use F12, you would believe F12 would be used as "normal", but resharper STILL maps F12 to its own use. So you need to remove all the resharper mappings for F12 like you described.

Comment: Doesn't work with visual studio professional 2017 veersion 15.6.2 and Resharper Ultimate 2017.2.2.

Answer (score 5):

Try simple way to enable it, press Fn + Esc key of the keyboard.

Comment: Yes works for me, so it's not a visual studio issue, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that you have enabled Fn mode (Blue Keys) on your keyboard which overrides default behavior of functional keys including F12.

Comment: Came here to add this as an answer. Make sure F-Lock is toggled if your keyboard has such a feature.

Comment: I've tried the hell all above and none helped. This is the best answer))

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with VS2013 and Resharper 9. I have a code like this:

```
gridList.Method1();
gridList.Method2();
```

I then right-click on any of `gridList` and click `Find Usages` (or just use `Shift+F12`) but it says "Usages not found" even though it is just one line away! Sometimes VS restart would help, sometimes it wouldn't. It looks like clearing the cache of Reshaper helps though: **Resharper -> Options -> Environment -> General -> Clear Caches**. This needs VS to be restarted, but then it started working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I couldn't use the command "Alt + F12" when trying to "peek definition" in Visual Studio. I found out through another forum-thread that it was Nvidia's GeForce Experience that overrides some of the "Alt" shortcuts and uses them for their functionalities with screen recordings etc.

What solved it for me, was going into the GeForce Experience settings and switch off the use of in-game overlay:

[image]

Alternatively, if you want to use the overlay, you can just change the short cut commands.

Comment: Oh man, this overlay has always had many bugs, but preventing me from coding comfortably is one bug too many. Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: @RobertSynoradzki You're welcome -- always glad to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

For ReSharper Ultimate 2017.3.3 and Visual Studio 2017:
Tools > Options > Tools > External Sources > Default Visual Studio Navigation > Save[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem after an organizational change that caused my windows profile to change. I tried the solutions listed above, but nothing seemed to work.
Here is how I fixed it (brute force worked!)

NOTE: Steps listed are for VS 2012 and ReSharper 7.1.3

1. Uninstalled Re-Sharper
2. Exit visual studio, ensure the process devenv.exe is no longer there in the running processes (was there in my case and I had to do a "End Process Tree" from Task Manager)
3. Fired up VS 2012, and from the menu Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard selected Visual C# 2005 (or any other setting you love) and pressed Reset
4. Shutdown VS again (and ensure devenv.exe has been killed in Task manager)
5. Re-installed re-sharper

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

These steps solved it for me:

1. Uninstall keyboard in Device Manager
2. Re-insert your keyboard usb

Answer (score 0):

**"Web Essentials"**
Add or update visual studio "Web Essentials" You can find it at:
**Menu>>Tools>>Extensions and Updates**

I hope this will save your time. It worked for me.

[image: Web Essentials]

Answer (score 0):

ReSharper added a <del>crap</del> 'good' new thing that they now call a feature: Smart Go To Declaration. As dumb as it may sound, it comes enabled by default: <del>crap</del> 'good'.

The feature is described on the link provided from [here](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207208195-Sometimes-Go-To-Definition-goes-to-Next-Usage) but honestly at least it should've keep it disabled, not reinvent the wheel. It also tells you how to disable that <del>crap</del> 'good' feature.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it has noting to do with Visual Studio at all. Be sure your keyboard has its function key setting of the keyboard itself to send the F12 function to Visual Studio.  It is an easy thing to miss.

Answer (score 0):

I had just installed Pulover’s Macro Creator and <kbd>F12</kbd> was set as the global hotkey to pause a macro. It was intercepting the keypress before it had a chance to get to VS.

Solution is to change that hotkey to something else. I chose Ctrl-F12. The input box is on the top right of the Pulover window.

[image: After changing the hotkey]

Answer (score 0):

Update 2020. I had the same problem and also tried a lot of ways, but that was still didn't working... [VS 2015, ReSharper 2019.3.1]
But, like Andrius said:
*Resharper -> Options -> Environment -> General -> Clear Caches. This needs VS to be restarted, but then it started working as expected.*

Summary is: (try steps above) + Resharper..-> Clear Caches + VS restart. Hope this will be useful

Comment: Same here. Unfortunately even after clearing all cache, resetting the shortcuts and applying the them, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Agree, unfortunately still not always working. Maybe good idea is report an issue?

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47073701/18337751) above, helped me to set up Shift+F12 (Find All References), only I was just looking for the option Edit.FindAllReferences

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsrLY.png)