# How to Re-enable F12 to Go To Definition After Installing Resharper in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper

In visual studio 2012, also should work with other versions:

Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard

In the box "Show commands containing:", type "Edit.GoToDefinition", then in the box "Press shortcut keys" hit F12 and click assign.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a how-to, and not a question.

Answer (score 23):

Enter **Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard** and press the Reset button. Click OK to save changes.

Then enter in **Resharper > Options > Environment > Keyboards & Menus**. Select Visual Studio and then press Apply Scheme button. Click Save to save changes.

Worked for me.

Credits to [F12 no longer works in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955193/f12-no-longer-works-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Thanks for the "Enter Tools > Options > Keyboard and press the Reset button".

Answer (score 9):

For Resharper 2019 / Visual Studio 2019 this can be changed via the resharper options, under Tools > External Sources. Resetting the keyboard scheme does nothing.

[image]

Comment: worked for me in vs 2022 where goto definition was broken when R# was active.

Answer (score 6):

The above didn't work for me. I had to remove all keyboard shorcuts and re-applying them:

**1)** Enter **Resharper > Options > Keyboard & Menus:**

[image]

**2)** Choose **None** and then **Apply Scheme:**

[image]

**3)** Repeat the above, this time choose **Visual Studio** scheme (don't forget to click **Apply Scheme**).

Answer (score 0):

Enter **Resharper > Environment > Keyboard & Menus**. Uncheck Override Visual Studio refactorings

Worked for me.